# Change TFDGUIxLoginDialog Caption and Text/Icon?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

In C++ Builder 11.3, on a `TFDConnection` using `SQLite` I enabled `LoginPrompt` and set the `LoginDialog` to a `TFDGUIxLoginDialog` on my data module. I setup a new custom caption but when I run the program the login caption is still **FireDAC Login**.

There is an icon there and text that reads **Enter your credentials**, how do I change those? Why is the custom caption not showing on the login dialog?

Also, I presume this special purpose dialog is secure and not just throwing the password around and leaving in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the issue of the `Caption` not working, it appears it was something to do with the IDE.   When I exited the IDE, deleted database, and opened the IDE, it asked for the password with that other dialog.  The database was also created.  So when it is `Connected` in the IDE, it was using its own login prompt.  Once I disabled that, I get the new prompt with multiple fields and my `Caption`.   I still don't have the answer how to customize the other items.